# Extract url from string (no regex)

Tags: php

I have a string which contains a `url`. I am trying to extract the `url` from the additional text in the most efficient way. So far I have been using explode but I have to explode twice and then rebuild the url. Regex is not something I dominate yet so i placed it out of the question(unless it is the best solution). Is there a way to extract the url in one step?

```
$url = "/url?q=http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778&sa=U&ei=EhHLVL_yJcb-yQSZ7oDgAg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg";
$strip1  = explode( '&', $url );
$strip2  = explode('=', $strip1[0]);
$result =  $strip2[1].'='.$strip2[2];
```

result:

```
http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:use **preg_split()**

```
$date = "/url?q=http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778&sa=U&ei=EhHLVL_yJcb-yQSZ7oDgAg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg";
$t =preg_split("/[=&]/",  $date);
echo $t[1]."=".$t[2]; //output: http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id1545778
```

Comment: @MaryCoding this may help you :)

Comment: unfortunately `split` is deprecated.

Comment: thanks, this works perfect as is simple and doesn't involve regex

Comment: @MaryCoding This is actually using a regex. `/[=&]/` is a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strip1  = explode( '/url?q=', $url );
```

Use this regex $strip1

```
^((http):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

you will get an array of sections in the url

Answer (score 0):

### Ugly one-step regex-free solution.

```
$url = "/url?q=http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778&sa=U&ei=EhHLVL_yJcb-yQSZ7oDgAg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg";
$result = substr( $url, strpos( $url, '=' ) + 1, strpos( $url, '&' ) - strpos( $url, '=' ) - 1 );
echo $result;
```

And cleaner two-step variation.

```
$url = "/url?q=http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778&sa=U&ei=EhHLVL_yJcb-yQSZ7oDgAg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg";
$start = strpos( $url, '=' ) + 1;
$result = substr( $url, $start, strpos( $url, '&' ) - $start );
echo $result;
```

### Somewhat less-ugly regex solution.

```
$url = "/url?q=http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778&sa=U&ei=EhHLVL_yJcb-yQSZ7oDgAg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg";
$result = preg_replace( '/[^=]*=([^&]*).*/', '${1}', $url );
echo $result;
```

Both produce the following output.

```
http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778
```

Comment: Looks like the regex by far seems to be cleaner than the other ways

Answer (score 0):

Technically, that second `?` in the URL should be URL encoded, but we can get around that. Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the query, then replace `?` with a URL encoded version using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). After this, you will have a valid query that you can parse using [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$query = str_replace("?", urlencode("?"), $query);
parse_str($query, $params);
echo $params['q'];

// displays http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "/url?q=http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778&sa=U&ei=EhHLVL_yJcb-yQSZ7oDgAg&ved=0CBMQFjAA&usg";

$strip3  = current(explode('&',end(explode('=', $url,2))));
print_r ($strip3);    //output  http://www.somesite.com/sites/pages/page?id=1545778
```

Comment: try this one using explode.